# is OR clause possible between 2 group by clause in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
FAMILY               LRU  SPRU  OPS

family1              12   34    12

sub family2          20  12    14
```

I want output something like above(pivote table),
there are 2 columns 
`family` and `sub_family`, and
I am looking something like

```
group by family OR group by sub_family
```

I need it in mysql am running phpmyadmin 5.5

Comment: Use `group by family,sub_family`

Comment: Provide use the table and some example data here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
select .. from ..  group by family, sub_family
```

the OR operator is not allowed here

Comment: that is not helping for my requirement

Comment: that is not helping for my requirement if i use -group by family, sub_family    ...because i will get data side by side ...i want all families should come in single column     first family group below that sub family group..